# Regex to filter list of numbers if it contains 51 in a certain location

Tags: regex

I have a list of numbers between 11 and 14 digits. The first two digits are always 00. I want to filter out any numbers that have "51" in position 4 and 5, e.g. 00*51******.

I created this Regex

```
^(00[1-9](?=(?![5]))(?=(?![1]))\d{8,11})$
```

but it is not doing "AND operation" and stops on !5. How should I set this "AND" correctly?

Examples:
0035196916180 - Should NOT match because of 00351
0033749593254 - Should match because there is no 00351
0035741368965 - Should match because there 0035"7" and not 1

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are looking for. Please add some positive and negative examples and the expected output. Your first sentence states not 00351***** but your "Regex logic should be..." sentence states the third digit can be any number (not just 3).

Comment: This maybe: `^00[1-9](?!51)\d{8,11}$`?

Comment: Thanks for the examples but what about position 3? In your first statement and examples it's always a 3 but in your logic description it states it can be any number.

Comment: 3rd position can be [1-9] any number.

Comment: Great... please edit your first sentence to match what you just stated.

Comment: Better, thanks. Are all numbers exactly 13 digits? If so, please state that in your question. Your examples all match that... just wanted to clarfiy.

Comment: To cover all numbers I think I can set it to 11-14

Comment: Great, that should be added to the question also.

Comment: @madial9663 does this works for you?? `^00[1-9](?!(?:51))[0-9]{8,11}$`

Comment: I've rewritten the question to hopefully be more concise and include all the info from your comments. If I've made any mistakes or stated something that isn't true, please correct them.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JeffC for your corrections, you taught how to ask question correctly:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your description and examples, I think this is what you are looking for

```
^00\d(?!51)\d{8,11}$
```

See it working on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xGeBi8/1).

Comment: Working great, as expected. Thanks a lot.